# Why does KDE Accessible / the screenreader start automatically and how to prevent it?

Tags: debian, kde, accessibility

I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE and KDE Accessible / the screenreader keeps appearing from time to time for some reason. I'd like to know *why* that is and how to prevent it from starting.
It's not listed in the autostart entries in Background Services nor in the BootUp-Manager (bum). In the Accessibility Options "Screen reader enabled" is not checked.

---

`ps -ef | grep access` gives me:

> /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
>   /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/kaccessibleapp

The content of /usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/uWc9aynL).

Comment: Maybe you hit the shortkey of it? I think it was `meta+alt+s`

Comment: I don't hit such uncommon shortcuts by accident. And this is happening on multiple machines. I verified that this is the shortcut of kaccess. Furthermore it's not starting when I hit that combo. I'm referring to that blue tray icon.

Comment: Well if it is useless to you just purge it? `sudo apt-get purge kaccessible`

Comment: Yes, but that's not a solution. I'd like to know _why_ it does start automatically because I didn't tell it to do so and that's strange.

Comment: Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398268/9158

Answer (score 3):

It's a session D-Bus service, defined in file `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.kaccessible.service`. It is started indirectly by `systemd`'s user session manager.

See `systemctl --user status`.

When a GUI desktop session begins, one of the user-level services started at that time is the *accessibility bus service*: `at-spi-dbus-bus.service`. It starts `at-spi-bus-launcher`, which in turn starts an instance of `dbus-daemon` for the accessibility bus, and the actual D-Bus services of the accessibility bus, including `kaccessibleapp`.

In order to disable just the `kaccessibleapp` service, as far as I can see, the file `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.kaccessible.service` would need to stop existing in that directory; there does not seem to be any other way to control the start-up of that service specifically.

If you want to disable the entire accessibility bus, run `systemctl --user stop at-spi-dbus-bus.service` as your regular user account, then verify nothing important to you is broken by that. If something is wrong, just logging out and back in restarts the accessibility bus again. To persistently disable the accessibility bus from starting, run `systemctl --user disable at-spi-dbus-bus.service`. To undo, replace `disable` with `enable`.

If some other session-level service requires the accessibility bus in its `systemd` configuration, the accessibility bus service may still get started to fulfill that requirement. To explicitly forbid the start of the accessibility bus even if something else requires it, run `systemctl --user mask at-spi-dbus-bus.service`. To undo, replace `mask` with `unmask`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so after some digging, I found a solution that worked for me by either editing the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/kaccess.desktop` and commenting `Exec=kaccess` line or deleting the whole file same thing for kdeconnect with `/org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop` file.

Answer (score -1):

#### Preamble

As one might expect from a piece of holdover software from the Plasma 4 days, KAccess also predates the existence of systemd, and is still yet to receive a thorough enough porting effort to integrate it with all of the current desktop infrastructure. In fact I'm a little amazed at the fact that when I saw your question and thought "Oh! I think I know just what the answer is to this one!" and pulled down a Yakuake window, my first `ls` command was to exactly the right directory despite it probably being 6-8 years since I fell victim to this issue myself. Here's the exact command I invoked and its output:

```bsh
$ ls -lFAhkp /etc/xdg/autostart/kaccess.desktop

  rw-r--r--   1   root   root      2 KiB   Thu Jan 21 13:01:43 2021    kaccess.desktop
```

#### The Perpetrator is found

That file right there is the source of all your frustrations, I'm sorry to report. And as satisfying as I know it would be to `rm -f` that thing to the gates of Hades, I'm going to have to counsel you in an altogether different direction. The reason is thus...

The file's recent mtime alerted me to the fact that it wasn't cruft, but most likely still a constituent of a current package within the KDE framework. In fact I soon discovered that it's not in just *any* package, but none other than `plasma-desktop` itself! This means that if you deleted it, the next time you used the package manager to update your system following a new set of `plasma-*` packages being issued, the file would be right back where it was. Luckily the legitimate, "According to Hoyle" solution is a quick one, at least.

#### Always consult an ancient scroll before attempting to slay a dragon

The whole `autostart` folder thing is yet another of the Freedesktop.org XDG (Cross-Desktop Group) Specifications, aptly named **[Desktop Application Autostart](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html)**, and this little nugget is tucked inside the [Implementation Notes](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html#idm45905922158896) paragraph:

> If an application autostarts by having a .desktop file installed in the system wide autostart directory, an individual user can disable the autotomatic start of this application by placing a .desktop file of the same name in its personal autostart directory which contains the key Hidden=true.

Earlier in the specification, the section on [Autostart Directories](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html#idm45905921787360) states:

> If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set the autostart directory for a user account is `~/.config/autostart`.
>
> If `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` is not set the system-wide autostart directory is `/etc/xdg/autostart`.

#### The conquering hero returns

All that being clear, this would be my approach to the situation, executed in a sufficiently sophisticated shell such as Bash or Z Shell to accommodate the.conditional variable expansion shown.

1. Ensure the autostart directory for your user account does, in fact, exist.

   `mkdir -pv "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}/autostart"`
2. Banish a copy of the offending plasma-desktop file to rot there for all eternity.

   `cp -iv /etc/xdg/autostart/kaccess.desktop "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}/autostart"`
3. After deleting any existing lines from the file that set a value for the Hidden key, use the spell from the scroll to curse it with a lifetime of impotence.

   ```bsh
   grep -Eq 'Hidden\s*?=' "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}/autostart/kaccess.desktop" &&
     sed -Ei '/Hidden[[:blank:]]*?=/d' "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}/autostart/kaccess.desktop";
   echo "Hidden=true" >>"${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}/autostart/kaccess.desktop"
   ```