# Why does Gnome 3 start "KDE Accessible"?

Tags: gnome, kde, gnome3

When I start a Gnome 3 session on Debian Linux 9, in the icons tray among others appears the icon of "KDE Accessible".

"KDE Accessible" is not in the list of Gnome's startup applications, neither is in my login Bash script.

Why does this KDE thing appears in my Gnome? How to make this program not to start automatically? It only clutters the icons tray.

Note: My question is similar to [Why does KDE Accessible / the screenreader start automatically and how to prevent it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/388218/9158) question, but my question is about it appearing in Gnome, not KDE as in that question.

Answer (score 2):

The KDE Accessible icon is the from the [kaccessible](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/utils/kaccessible) package.

If you don't need kaccessible you can remove with it with the Apt Package Manager:

`sudo apt-get remove kaccessible`

Comment: Thanks, but your answer does not explain why it auto-starts